# Midi kick drum triggering with my shoe?

Tags: performing, midi

I'm a one-man-band and need a better way to use my shoe for producing a kick drum sound. I move around a lot on stage and need a method that can attach to my shoe. Right now I'm using a clip on piezo contact microphone, with a compressor pedal to control the sound and EQ out all but the low frequencies. As you can imagine the results are inconsistent. I was thinking about instead using the clip-mic as a midi trigger with a small sound module. Any suggestions for the methodology and gear that would give me the best results?

Comment: You might want to look at a drum trigger plugin. Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with any, but the general idea (take drum-like sound as input and output MIDI) might do what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Go buy a midi drum module, either new or used (they were very popular in the 1980s and have quarter-inch audio jacks) and some acoustic drum triggers.  Take a pair of converse tennis shoes (trainers) with very thin soles and slit the sole to insert the drum triggers.  I've used this method to get a kick drum from my heels and snare and high hat from the balls of my feet.

Or build a stomp board or stomp box which is a wooden box or platform with a contact mic or transducer built in.  You can build a stomp board in any dimension you choose.

If you play on wooden stages you could also simply place a contact mic on the stage floor and put a switch in the circuit to mute it when desired.  Put some taps on your feet and you can do drum solos.

Finally, if you carry a fair amount of gear, you can build a suitcase bass drum with any standard forward or backward hitting drum pedal.